# Multiple swipe events on an element with TouchSwipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I would like to bind multiple swipe events on a DOM element with [TouchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin). The [demo](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/) does not have an example with multiple events. I tried the follwing:

```
$("#test").swipe( {

    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
    swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        alert("you swiped " + direction);
    },
    //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
    threshold:10
});

$("#test").swipe( {

    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
    swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        alert("you swiped " + direction);
    },
    //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
    threshold:10
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xktJ9/

But unfortunately, only the first event fires (see fiddle).

Is this possible with the TouchSwipe library? If yes, how? If no, can you recommend a library which is capable of binding multiple events on an element?

Comment: instead of adding event... you can check `direction` using `direction` parameter

Comment: Yes, this is how i'm doing it right now. But unfortunately these events have to be added/removed dynamically. I could write my own mechanism to register/unregister for events but i'd rather have this handled by a library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the swipeStatus method of touchSwipe instead of swipeRight or swipeLeft.

```
    $("#test").swipe( {
     swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
     {
       //Here we can check the:
       //phase : 'start', 'move', 'end', 'cancel'
       //direction : 'left', 'right', 'up', 'down' 
       //distance : Distance finger is from initial touch point in px
       //duration : Length of swipe in MS 
       //fingerCount : the number of fingers used
       if (phase=="end" && (direction == 'left' || direction == 'right')) {
         alert("you swiped " + direction);
       }
     },
     //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
     threshold:10,
     maxTimeThreshold:5000,
     fingers:'all'
   });
```

For more details please see this: [link](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Swipe_status.html)

Comment: @leo, any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how I add multiple swipe events .

```
$("#demo1").swipe( {
    //Single swipe handler for left swipes
    swipeRight:function() {
            demo1.goToPrevSlide();
                return false;
    }
    ,

    swipeLeft:function() {
            demo1.goToNextSlide();
                return false;
    },excludedElements:"",
    allowPageScroll:"vertical",
    preventDefaultEvents:false
    })
```