# TouchSwipe - multiple events on one swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I'm using TouchSwipe jQuery plugin for mobile version of my site. I need to fire multiple click-events on one swipe, something like - on every 15px of swipe - one click. I've googled, but found no solution.

Thing is - I'm using carousel plugin for Joomla (sigplus), that, unfortunately, doesn't support finger swipe. I'm trying to emulate swiping function by making TouchSwipe pressing carousel buttons for user on swipe. At the moment I have such code:

```
 jQuery(function($) {

$(".s2").swipe({
    excludedElements: "button, input, select, textarea, .noSwipe",

  swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
     $( '.boxplus-next' ).click();
  }, 
  swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
     $('.boxplus-prev').click();

  },
  triggerOnTouchEnd:false,
  threshold:15
});

});
```

It works fine, but scrolls only one image in carousel per touch. Maybe it's possible to restart function after triggering?

Thanks

P.S. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger continuous events, you should use the *swipeStatus* event instead: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Swipe_status.html

You can then trigger next or back, based on the distance.

See this answer for more info: [Multiple swipe events on an element with TouchSwipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400692/multiple-swipe-events-on-an-element-with-touchswipe)